# input dynamic form with unique id

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to dynamically create form input. while I make it static as below.

html

```
<input type="text" id="try1" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="try2" style="display: none"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="try3" style="display: none"/>
```

javascript

```
$("#try1").live("input", function(){
    a = $(this).val();
    if (a.length >= 3){
        $("#try2").show();
    }
    else if (a.length <=3){
        $("#try2").hide();
    }

});

$("#try2").live("input", function(){
    a = $(this).val();
    if (a.length >= 3){
        $("#try3").show();
    }
    else if (a.length <=3){
        $("#try3").hide();
    }

});
```

how to have input into a dynamic form, when filled with characters more than 3 then the new input form will appear underneath. help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script>

 var counter=2;
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("input").live('keyup', function(){
        var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
        a = $('#'+currentID).val();

        if (a.length >= 3){
            $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'try'+counter, name: 'try'+counter }).appendTo('#appenddiv');
            counter++;

        }
        else if (a.length <=3){
            $('#try'+currentID).remove();

        }
    });



});

</script>
<input type="text" id="try1" /><br/>
<div id= "appenddiv">

</div>
```

Comment: Quote from jQuery website: '*As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().*' It's currently up to 1.8.2